# How to stop checking node_modules

Tags: visual-studio-code

In small projects I love MS Code's auto linting. But the moment the project starts to pull in npm dependencies it becomes useless

[image: Completely unnecessary errors]

Is there a way to configure certain folders to not be checked? I'm aware of `"search.excludeFolders"` but it doesn't help at all with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using TypeScript, you can create a [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) file and choose one of the 3 options:

1. Provide an explicit list of files to compile, thus preventing any of the `node_modules/*` from showing errors.
2. Do not provide an explicit list of files (by default all `./**/*.ts` files will be compiled), but put `tsconfig.json` inside your source folder, with `node_modules` automatically excluded from compilation.
3. Use the new [`exclude`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3188) feature in `tsconfig.json` (available soon).

Comment: So I take it exclude isn't available just yet?

Comment: It should be available after the next compiler update (probably version 1.5-final).

Comment: sorry. I'm rather new to ts. How fast has 1.5 been moving? I've spent 2 days wrangling a lot of tsd issues and compiling issues and I'm wondering if it's worth the struggle

Comment: TS is worth every hour you put into it. There's no official estimate for 1.5 right now (not that I know of), but it should be released pretty soon, since beta came out almost 3 months ago.

Comment: Ah awesome. I'm very excited to use. it.